# Why does SwiftUI automatically navigate backwards when my underlying data source is updated and how can I avoid this behavior?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-navigationview

I have a fairly common set up:

- A list of items created using the `ForEach` component
- When an item is tapped my app navigates to a detailed view
- Inside of the detailed view, the user can perform updates that change the underlying item

The problem is that updating the underlying item (which is a struct) causes SwiftUI to automatically navigate backward. I assume this is because the struct is an immutable value and gets destroyed during the update, however, it does conform to `Identifiable` so I'm expecting SwiftUI to understand that the item still exists and just needs to be updated rather than destroyed.

**Is there any way to update the underlying list without navigating away from the detail view?**

Here's a minimal, reproducible example.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
       DemoList(viewModel: ViewModel())
    }
}

struct DemoItem: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: UInt
    var description: String
}

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var list = [
        DemoItem(id: 1, description: "One"),
        DemoItem(id: 2, description: "two")
    ]
    
    /// This update causes SwiftUI to automatically navigate away from the detail view
    func update(item: DemoItem) {
        list = list.map { $0.id == item.id ? item : $0 }
    }
}

struct DemoList: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ForEach(viewModel.list, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: DemoDetail(viewModel: self.viewModel, item: item)) {
                    Text(item.description)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DemoDetail: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var item: DemoItem
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.description)
            .onTapGesture {
                let newItem = DemoItem(id: self.item.id, description: UUID().uuidString)
                self.viewModel.update(item: newItem)                
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the id from the ForEach and it'll stop navigating back

```
ForEach(viewModel.list) { item in
      NavigationLink(destination: DemoDetail(viewModel: self.viewModel, item: item)) {
      Text(item.description)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that works! Would you mind explaining why that works?

Comment: That's because you are invalidating the NavigationLink, have a look at the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302913/swiftui-navigationlink-pops-immediately-if-used-within-foreach

Answer (score 3):

This should fix your problem:

```
NavigationView {
    //Your views here
}.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

This is happening due to a bug in *iOS 15.0.1*.
You can find the details from this [forum thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665369)